# Is there a browser router tool?

Tags: macos, web-browser, url

I use many different browsers for different purposes - private, work, development and so on.
And when I click on a link in some app I would like it to be opened in the specific browser depending on some rules.

Literally it should be an app which is registered in system as a default browser and reopens the link in a one of the real browsers.

Is there any app like this?
Does API allow detecting installed browsers and opening appropriate browser?